# How to access the Tracked Object Offset in the Body of CinemachineVirtualCamera?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera, cinemachine

I'm new to Unity Cinemachine and I'm trying to change the y value of the Tracked Object Offset in the Body of CinemachineVirtualCamera using code. [image]

I read some articles for changing the value and what I currently have on my code is

```
private CinemachineCameraOffset cinemachineOffset;
Void Start() {
    cinemachineOffset.m_Offset = this.transform.localToWorldMatrix * new Vector3(0, 20, 0);
}
```

Then I get the error message saying `NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object`, and when I print out the value of `cinemachineOffset`, I get null, so I think I'm not doing right. So I was wondering how I can access the Y value of the CinemachineVirtualCamera of the Body...

Comment: Do you have the 'Target Object' attribute set in the inspector of the CinemachineCam?

Answer (score 1):

You need to get access to your framing transposer object like:

`yourCamera.GetComponentInChildren<CinemachineFramingTransposer>()`

and then you have access to any variable that your framing transposer has.